# Can't get "products ordered" collection with configurable products included (top 10 products)

Tags: magento-1.7, product-collection, reports, best-seller

I'm trying to develop a module to display top 10 bestseller products for each category. (I'll use it on home page for overall top 10 products too)

I have bundle, configurable and simple products in my store. And I would like to list top 10 for category A like this

1. Product X (simple)
2. Product Y (configurable - with 3 child products, all childs are invisible on store)
3. Product Z (bundle)
4. Product W (simple)...

When I check the reports section, the bestseller products report doesnt list configurable products as a parent product, instead it lists all child products as a seperate sales record. That is acceptable if I would like to see which child products performed better but it is useless at the frontend. I can see the report I need at **Reports** > **Product** > **Products Ordered** section, I've tried to debug its execution to see how it populates the list there. It's using **soldAction** at the "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Report/ProductController.php".

I am currently using the below code for testing, you can see the method I'm using to populate collection on model file. This doesn't list the configurable/bundle products, it just skips them and lists single products only.

- config.xml

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
      <modules>
          <Fit_Statistics>
              <version>0.1.0</version>
          </Fit_Statistics>
      </modules>
      <global>
          <models>
              <fit_statistics>
                  <class>Fit_Statistics_Model</class>
                  <resourceModel>fit_statistics_resource</resourceModel>
              </fit_statistics>
              <fit_statistics_resource>
                  <class>Fit_Statistics_Model_Resource</class>
              </fit_statistics_resource>
          </models>
          <blocks>
              <fit_statistics>
                  <class>Fit_Statistics_Block</class>
              </fit_statistics>
          </blocks>
          <helpers>
              <fit_statistics>
                  <class>Fit_Statistics_Helper</class>
              </fit_statistics>
          </helpers>
      </global>
  </config>
  ```
- Model/Top/Overall.php

  ```
  class Fit_Statistics_Model_Top_Overall extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
  {

      public function getBestsellersOverall()
      {
          $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

          $products = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')->addOrderedQty()->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image')
          )
                          ->setStoreId($storeId)->addStoreFilter($storeId)->setOrder('ordered_qty', 'desc'); //best sellers on top



          return $products;
      }
  }
  ```
- Block/Top/Overall.php

  ```
  class Fit_Statistics_Block_Top_Overall extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
      public function getBestsellerProducts()
      {
          $arr_products = array();
          $products     = Mage::getModel("fit_statistics/top_overall")->getBestsellersOverall();

          foreach($products as $product) {
              $arr_products[] = array('id' => $product->getId(), 'name' => $product->getName(), 'url' => $product->getProductUrl(),);
          }

          return $arr_products;
      }
  }
  ```
- frontend/base/default/template/fit_statistics/top/overall.phtml

  ```
  <?php
  $products = $this->getBestsellerProducts();
  ?>

  <div id="product_list">
      <h1>Bestseller Products</h1>
      <?php if (is_array($products) && count($products)) { ?>
          <?php foreach($products as $product) { ?>
              <div>
                  <a href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>"><?php echo $product['name'] ?></a>
              </div>
          <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
  </div>
  ```
- frontend CMS block

  ```
  {{block type="fit_statistics/recent_products" name="fit_statistics_recent_products" template="fit_statistics/recent/products.phtml"}}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The composite products are not included in the reports.
Take a look at the method `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection::addOrderedQty`

It contains these lines

```
$compositeTypeIds     = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_type')->getCompositeTypes();
```

and later

```
    $productJoinCondition = array(
        $adapter->quoteInto('(e.type_id NOT IN (?))', $compositeTypeIds),
        'e.entity_id = order_items.product_id',
        $adapter->quoteInto('e.entity_type_id = ?', $this->getProductEntityTypeId())
    );
```

As you can see the composite products (configurable, grouped, bundle) are not included in the report.
You can rewrite the `Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Product_Collection` class, add a new method similar to `addOrderedQty` from which you remove the restriction mentioned above and it might work.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for your reply. I've checked the code you pointed there but when i check the report at Reports > Product > Products Ordered, I can see all configurable products are displayed with the total count of all child products of them. I was asking how can I use the same method to populate my own collection. You can see my report screenshot below.

http://pasteboard.co/24UnYUis.jpg